# Is there a way to change the color of LSP generated virtual text in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the attached image, the `[i32; 3]` is virtual text (read only) automatically generated by LSP, however, I check VSCode official documents [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide), I didn't find out a way to override the color of the generated virtual text. Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: it differs per theme, so the color must be possible to customize

Comment: @rioV8 yes, you are correct, that's why I want to find out the way or the name of that content in color setting...

Comment: what does the TextMate scope inspector say, if it is a decorator then you must find out the theme name they use in the decorator

Comment: @rioV8 you mean Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes? Unfortunately this doesn't work, when I put cursor to the virtual text, it only shows the editor background information, nothing about text

Comment: then in the Theme used find a grey color and try to change the color for that theme name, or inspect the source of the LSP where they construct the decorator for these Hints

Comment: Please provide exact instructions to reproduce the issue. Ex. What exensions need to be installed? What language is this code in (rust? TS? kotlin?)? Provide a transcription of the code as formatted text (in a code block), etc.

Comment: @rioV8 find gray color way works.. now I found it..

Answer (score 1):

With hint from @rioV8, I found the color definition in theme json file, it is called `badge.foreground`, I hope this will help others who have the same requirement